# CAS client for Tomcat 8 or 9

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

Has anybody been able to configure a CAS Client running on Tomcat 8 or 9? The examples I found are only for version 6 and 7. I tried to create a web app in Tomcat 9 using the CAS Tomcat 7 client but I'm getting errors suggesting that the LoginConfig was moved in Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pull requests available now to support Jetty and Tomcat8:
https://github.com/Jasig/java-cas-client/pulls

Comment: Yes, great. I did submit the Tomcast8 pull request. Thanks for accepting it.